# can OpenGL share context with different version

Tags: macos, opengl

As Mac only support OpenGL 2.1 and core profile, is it possible to share objects between a 2.1 thread and a core profile thread? For example a version 2.1 context and a 3.2 core profile context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At least not officially. From "OpenGL Programming Guide on Mac: Working with Rendering Contexts" (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_contexts/opengl_contexts.html):

> Not every context can be shared with every other context. Both contexts must share the same OpenGL profile.

In this case, one context would use the compatibility profile, the other the core profile. So different profiles, and no sharing.